# How to center vertically and horizontaly a div with Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm learning Tailwind CSS and I'm having this problem. I did this:
[My div with its buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/964tM.png)

And I would like to center it vertically, but when I use flex, this happens:
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7I98.png)

This is my code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white max-w-lg mx-auto p-8 md:p-12 my-10 rounded-lg shadow-2xl">
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center">¿Who are you?</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-5">
        <button className="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Admin</button>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-5">
        <button className="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Client</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: try using flex flex-col items-center justify-center

Comment: I think you should give this component's parent these classes `flex justify-center items-center`, and the parent div should have specific height of 100% to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a div wrapper and add flex class to it like this

**Your code**

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center flex-col m-auto h-screen">
     <div className="bg-white w-1/3 mx-auto  p-8 md:p-12 my-10 rounded-lg shadow-2xl">
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center">¿Who are you?</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-5">
        <button className="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Admin</button>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-5">
        <button className="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Client</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
  )
}
```

**Live Demo**

https://play.tailwindcss.com/inCNN5fhkb

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers, I did it in this way:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center flex-col m-auto h-screen">
      <div className="bg-white w-1/4 mx-auto p-8 my-12 rounded-lg shadow-2xl">
        <div>
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center">¿Who are you?</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-5">
          <Link href='/admin/index.js'>
            <button className="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Admin</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-5">
          <Link href='/client/index.js'>
            <button className="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Client</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="w-full h-screen flex">
  <div class="bg-white max-w-lg mx-auto p-8 md:p-12 my-10 rounded-lg shadow-2xl place-self-center">
    <div>
      <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">¿Who are you?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
      <button class="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Admin</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
      <button class="bg-indigo-600 rounded-sm w-full p-3 text-white uppercase font-bold hover:bg-indigo-700 cursor-pointer transition-color">Client</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After it just rename **class** for ***className***